# Qt QColor and QBrush on a GraphicsView?

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qcolor

How would you set a custom color using RBG values to a QBrush? And then draw a rectangle with the brush on a GraphicsView.

So far I've tried:

```
QBrush *goldBrush = new QBrush(QColor(212,175,55));
scene->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,goldBrush);
```

The error message is:

> error: C2664: 'QGraphicsRectItem
>   *QGraphicsScene::addRect(qreal,qreal,qreal,qreal,const QPen &,const QBrush &)' : cannot convert argument 6 from 'QBrush *' to 'const
>   QBrush &' Reason: cannot convert from 'QBrush *' to 'const QBrush' No
>   constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
>   resolution was ambiguous

Then when I replace the first line with:

```
const QBrush *goldBrush = new QBrush(QColor(212,175,55));
```

The message is only slightly changed to:

> error: C2664: 'QGraphicsRectItem
>   *QGraphicsScene::addRect(qreal,qreal,qreal,qreal,const QPen &,const QBrush &)' : cannot convert argument 6 from 'const QBrush *' to 'const
>   QBrush &' Reason: cannot convert from 'const QBrush *' to 'const
>   QBrush' No constructor could take the source type, or constructor
>   overload resolution was ambiguous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace "scene->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,goldBrush);" with "scene->addRect(0,415,20,50,noPen,***goldBrush**);". The way you are doing it, you are passing an adress to a position on the memory instead of a reference to the variable.